Understanding survival curves with time-dependent covariates
In an observational cohort study, I want to assess the impact of exposure to a given prescription drug on mortality. Out of 841,161 patients, 150,279 (17.9%) died during follow-up. Exposure is a time-dependent covariate with 3 levels (not exposed, normal dose, high dose). I am using R and the survival package.
I have prepared a counting process form dataset. So far there seems to be no problem (regarding the late count, I have double checked, it is ok):
ben |>
  subset(select = c(id, time_death, death, tstart, tstop, exposure)) |>
  head()
#     id time_death death tstart    tstop    exposure
# 1 id-1   806 days FALSE      0  81 days Normal dose
# 2 id-1   806 days FALSE     81 806 days Not exposed
# 3 id-2  1446 days FALSE      0  35 days Normal dose
# 4 id-2  1446 days FALSE     35  50 days Not exposed
# 5 id-2  1446 days FALSE     50 147 days Normal dose
# 6 id-2  1446 days FALSE    147 184 days Not exposed

summary(ben)
# Call:
# tmerge(data1 = ben, data2 = period, id = id, 
#     exposure = tdc(time_exposure, exposure))
# 
#          early  late gap  within boundary leading trailing tied missid
# death        0     0   0       0        0       0   841161    0      0
# exposure     0 34746   0 7155602        0  841161      913    0      0

survcheck(Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ 1, ben, id = id)
# Call:
# survcheck(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ 1, data = ben, 
#     id = id)
# 
# Unique identifiers       Observations        Transitions 
#             841161            7996763             150279 
# 
# Transitions table:
#       to
# from        1 (censored)
#   (s0) 150279     690882
#   1         0          0
# 
# Number of subjects with 0, 1, ... transitions to each state:
#        count
# state        0      1
#   1     690882 150279
#   (any) 690882 150279
# 

Now, I want to plot Kaplan-Meier curves. However, according to the plot, the event probability is much higher than I expected (i.e. up to 25% in the not exposed patients, while there is only 17.9% of death overall in the dataset). On the other hand, the number of events is as expected (i.e. $115899 + 33512 + 868 = 150279$):
survfit(Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ exposure, ben)
# Call: survfit(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ exposure, data = ben)
# 
#                      records  n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# exposure=Not exposed 3980754 634383  320023 115899     NA      NA      NA
# exposure=Normal dose 3928060 829013  829013  33512     NA      NA      NA
# exposure=High dose     87949  12148   12148    868     NA      NA      NA


Trying to decipher this, I also inspected the plot from an univariate Cox model. The event probability is high again:
survfit(coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ exposure, ben))
# Call: survfit(formula = coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, death) ~ exposure, 
#     ben))
# 
#      records      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# [1,] 7996763 841161 150279     NA      NA      NA


I have read several discussions about whether Kaplan-Meier curves are appropriate with time-dependent covariates. From what I understand, this seems to be the case:

(...) the fundamental use of survfit() with a Surv(startTime, stopTime, event) outcome variable is certainly a valid way to display Kaplan-Meier curves with time-varying covariates.

As per @EdM comment, here are the density plot of death times, and the density plot of last observation times for those who did not die:
ben |>
  subset(death, time_death, drop = TRUE) |>
  density() |>
  plot(main = "Death times")
ben |>
  subset(!death, time_death, drop = TRUE) |>
  density() |>
  plot(main = "Last observation times for those who did not die")



I am wondering whether I really understand what I am looking at when inspecting survival curves with time-dependent covariates. Are these curves compatible with 17.9% of death in the dataset? Otherwise, does it seem to be an issue in the code?

This might be due to individuals having last observation times (with censored event times) at an early "Time since inclusion." Risk estimates at later times are based on the observed numbers of individuals with events, but the total "at-risk" numbers in the denominator of the cumulative risk calculations are lower than at early times. Thus the addition to cumulative probability at late times is higher than you would expect from simple total numbers and events. Could you perhaps show two density plots: one of death times, the other of last observation times for those without events?

@Edm: Thank you very much, this is very useful! I have edited the question to add the plots. In fact, we are most interested in the first 2 years following the drug initiation (i.e. the two first years of follow-up). Maybe I should censor at 2 years? However, I am very interested to how I can deal with the situation with the complete follow-up.

There's nothing wrong here. If there is any loss to follow up at times before the last time that you estimate the survival probability, then the fraction of all individuals who experience an event during the course of a survival study will be lower than the model-estimated probability of an event at that last time.
Although your data show pretty complete follow up for the first 2 years, that's followed by an almost uniform loss of individuals (without events) through the 7-year total study period. The estimated probabilities that you question are near the end of that 7-year period.
A simple way to think about this is that some individuals who left the study before 7 years would have experienced the event if they were followed for the full 7 years. Survival analysis takes that right censoring of event times into account, effectively adjusting the estimates to show higher event probabilities than the simple ratio of total events to total individuals.
More formally, consider the Nelson-Aalen estimate of the cumulative hazard as a function of time, $\bar \Lambda(t)$, in a model without covariates. It's not quite the same as the Kaplan-Meier estimate, but it makes the underlying principle easier to see. Recall that the survival as a function of (continuous) time is $S(t)=\exp[-\Lambda (t)]$, allowing you to translate the cumulative hazard (approximately) to survival or event probability.
With $\Delta \bar N(t_i)$ the number of events at time $t_i$ and $\bar Y(t_i)$ the total number at risk at that time, Equation 2.2 of Therneau and Grambsch shows :
$$\bar \Lambda(t) = \sum_{i:t_i \le t} \frac{\Delta \bar N(t_i)}{\bar Y(t_i)}.$$
Insofar as $Y(t)$ decreases for any reason other than a terminal event, the model-estimated hazard and event probability will be higher than the crude ratio of events to total individuals.

Thanks! I am glad to hear that "There's nothing wrong here"! Also, I have something to dig into to understand why. I feel that my upvotes are rather insignificant considering how much your responses have helped me and my colleagues with this study. If you agree, we'd like to thank you in our upcoming article. What do you think?

@Thomas you might thank the Cross Validated community, if you'd like and the reviewers/editors will let you. No need for personal thanks. What I write is based on what I've learned from participation with many others on this site.
